# Qt QFileInfo::exists() returns true in C://Program Files

Tags: c++, qt

It seems that on Windows I can't write to the Program Files or Program Files (x86) directories or their sub-directories anymore.

What I don't understand is how my app is letting that happen when I'm checking the following things

```
QFile newfile("C://Program Files/target.rar");
QFileInfo newfileInfo("C://Program Files/target.rar");

newfile.exists(); //returns true
newfile.isWritable(); // returns true
newfileInfo.exists(); // returns true
newfileInfo.isWritable(); // returns true
```

none of those should return true in Program Files.
Strangely it actually proceeds to write to this non-existent file, even though nothing is there, and it produces no write errors.

Comment: I suspect Windows may be opening / writing files in a virtualized folder instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be a victim of [UAC Virtualization](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2010/08/11/uac-virtualization-allowing-standard-users-to-update-a-system-protected-area.aspx). Check `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files` to see whether your file is there.

Comment: I am!! I have just figured it out after reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640730/qt-cannot-cannot-create-write-to-c